# Xamarin throwing error when import converter into xaml

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-core

I have a xaml file where I'm importing a converter, but when I try to compile
Visual Studio thrown an exception with the message "Failed to resolve assembly: 'X'". The converter is in the same project and I imported a behavior from the same project and it worked well. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if it is a problem from xamarin or visual studio.

This is my Converter

```
namespace YogaMobileApp.Converters
{
    public class BoolNegation:IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(bool))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

            return !(bool)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(bool))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

            return !(bool)value;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my Xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:YogaMobileApp.Converters"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="YogaMobileApp.Views.LoginPage"
             d:BackgroundColor="White"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             BackgroundColor="White">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:BoolNegation x:Name="negation" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

 ...
</ContentPage>

///

When I try to compile vs throw an error "Failed to resolve assembly: 'YogaMobileApp' "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line seems to be wrong which probably causes such error, it should be:

```
<converters:BoolNegation x:Key="negation" />
```

Comment: Why is it wrong? I used the same approach that it is used in the [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters)

Comment: Did you actually read the page that you refer to? Because it exactly says that this line is wrong.

Comment: show me what is wrong? How to fix it! I didn't realize something is wrong in that line.

Comment: I've shown you above, you should use x:Key instead of x:Name